# Openstack remote console

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I've recently installed OpenStack Ussuri via Juju and it is working fine. I've installed almost all of the cloud ready images (qcow2). The problem is that when I install Ubuntu Cloud 20.04, I can't see the prompt from Spice console although I can see the Ubuntu prompt on the Log tab and I can connect to the instance via SSH. For the other distros like Fedora, CentOS and Cirros I dont have this problem.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/doOgJ.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hiWy.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2CWt.png]

Research I've completed suggests using settings on my nova computes like the below, however none of them are working:

```
hw_machine_type = x86_64=pc-i440fx-focal
virt_type = kvm
hw_disk_bus = ide
```

Does anyone know anything about the issue, and the best way to resolve it?

PS: Why does the image format for Ubuntu Cloud use IMG while the command `qemu-img info ubunutu.img` shows the file format as being qcow2?

Comment: Check the kernel command line.